# Reverse an sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have an sql file with alot of create, alterings and modifies to a database. If I need to back out at some point (up to a day maybe) after executing the sql script, is there an easy way to do that? For example, is there any tool to read an sql script and produce a 'rollback' script from it?

I am using sqlyog aswell, in case there happens to be any such features built-in (I havn't found any)

Comment: I think you need the PsychicSQl forum

Comment: The only option you may have is to restore to a backup. See [Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using the Binary Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) and [Database Backup Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html). Note that these are time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry, there are many statements that cannot be reversed from looking at the SQL command.

- `DROP TABLE` (what was in the table that dropped?)
- `UPDATE mytable SET timestamp = NOW()` (what was the timestamp before?)
- `INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (NULL)` (assuming id is auto-increment, what row was created?)

Many others...

If you want to recover the database from before your day's worth of changes, take a backup before you begin changing it.

You can also do [point-in-time recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) using binary logs, to restore the database to any moment since your last backup.